# Does Revelation actually imply that the "stars" hit the ground or only that they fall towards it?

Tags: greek, revelation, prepositions

Revelation 6:13 ESV

> and the stars of the sky fell to the earth as the fig tree sheds its winter fruit when shaken by a gale.

> καὶ οἱ ἀστέρες τοῦ οὐρανοῦ ἔπεσαν εἰς τὴν γῆν, ὡς συκῆ βάλλει τοὺς ὀλύνθους αὐτῆς ὑπὸ ἀνέμου μεγάλου σειομένη,

Does the Greek shed any light on whether these stars are depicted as actually hitting the ground or if they are only said to fall towards it?

Comment: Are you asking about the intended metaphor or about actual stars?

Comment: Whatever the Stars are, does the Greek say that they are hitting the ground or that they are only falling towards it?

Comment: Somewhat related:

[Rev 8:10-11 NASB95] [10] The third angel sounded, and a great star fell from heaven, burning like a torch, and it fell on a third of the rivers and on the springs of waters. [11] The name of the star is called Wormwood; and a third of the waters became wormwood, and many men died from the waters, because they were made bitter.

Comment: Also somewhat related:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ScbNEg7tjTc

Answer (score 3):

The Greek of Rev 6:13 is quite clear and even removes any doubt by providing a metaphor.  Let me quote the very literal BLB:

> and the stars of heaven fell to the earth, as a fig tree casts its
> unripe figs, being shaken by a great wind.

The operative preposition here is εἰς (eis) which is literally, "into, in, onto, toward" the earth.  However, lest there be any doubt John provides a very common metaphor of figs falling on the ground when the fig tree is shaken by a wind - the figs first fall toward the earth and then fall onto the ground!  The figs may be scattered but must ultimately fall on the ground.

The verb used here of the figs is βάλλω (ballo) which means, "to throw, cast, rush".  That is, the image here is something being thrown down.

Answer (score 0):

What an excellent question regarding interpretation . . . and a difficult one!

Certainly, John the Revelator had visions that he himself had to interpret. These visions might have been realistic or symbolic (or some of both), but it seems that just as the *Nevi’im* (prophets) of ancient times, John struggled to articulate what he saw.

Here are some points to consider when working on this interpretation.

1. Revelation is absolutely stuffed with allusions to the *Tanakh* (Old Testament).  What are some of these allusions in this case? For example, in Job 38:7 (ESV), we read, “. . . when the morning stars sang together and all the sons of God shouted for joy?” Here, there’s an association between the morning stars singing and the sons of God shouting for joy.
2. John’s ability to interpret what he saw was limited by his first-century experiences and influenced by his knowledge of the scriptures and the Messianic community of his day.
3. It’s certain that John did not understand much of what he saw and heard. For example, in Revelation 7:13-14 (ESV), we read

> Then one of the elders addressed me, saying, “Who are these,
> clothed in white robes, and from where have they come?” I said to
> him, “Sir, you know.” And he said to me, “These are the ones coming
> out of the great tribulation. They have washed their robes and made
> them white in the blood of the Lamb.

So, what are the possibilities for interpretation in this case?

a.  The stars are purely metaphorical or symbolic. The angels of the seven churches in Revelation 2 and 3 are described as seven stars. The stars in Revelation 6 might also be angels. Revelation 12:4 (ESV) states that “His [the dragon’s] tail swept down a third of the stars of heaven and cast them to the earth.” Yes, they land on earth.

b.  Taken in context, Revelation 6:12-17 (ESV) also includes “The sky vanished like a scroll that is being rolled up” and that “Then the kings of the earth and the great ones and the generals and the rich and the powerful, and everyone, slave and free, hid themselves in the caves and among the rocks of the mountains . . .” So if these “stars” are symbolic, are the “kings of the earth” also symbolic?

c.  A symbolic/historical interpretation would be that all these visions pertained to the Roman Empire during and after the life of John the Revelator. Perhaps, there are parallels between the first Roman Empire and a second Roman Empire in the future. The stars symbolically land on earth.

d.  A literal/visual interpretation would be that whatever John saw, they appeared to be like stars to him. What would it look like to you if the earth encountered an extremely heavy meteor shower? What would it look like if the earth encountered a very heavy shower of asteroids? What would 6,000 rockets falling on Israel look like? Remember that in the night sky, there are only about 9,100 stars visible. They may or may not actually hit the earth.

e.  A literal/equivalent interpretation would be that whatever John saw was the *equivalent* of stars falling to the earth as would be the case in a heavy nuclear war, where each missile was armed with a thermonuclear warhead. One of these “stars” was actually given a name (perhaps by people on earth) in Revelation 8:10-11 (ESV):

> The third angel blew his trumpet, and a great star fell from heaven,
> blazing like a torch, and it fell on a third of the rivers and on the
> springs of water. The name of the star is Wormwood. A third of the
> waters became wormwood, and many people died from the water, because
> it had been made bitter.

In this case, people likely didn’t die symbolically but from drinking water polluted by Wormwood. *Coincidentally*, there’s a town in the Ukraine that’s named “Wormwood.” In the Ukrainian language, the word, Wormwood, is *Chernobyl*, which is the location of the 1986 nuclear reactor catastrophe. Because languages change over time, I double-checked this definition in an *old* Ukrainian dictionary. It’s also my understanding that in 1986, this connection sent many Ukrainians diving for their Bibles. This star contaminated the earth with radioactive material.

Also note that in the previous two verses, we read

> The second angel blew his trumpet, and something like a great
> mountain, burning with fire, was thrown into the sea, and a third of
> the sea became blood. A third of the living creatures in the sea died,
> and a third of the ships were destroyed.

How would a first-century prophet describe a large asteroid hitting the ocean?

f.  A completely literal interpretation would have stars falling to the earth, which sounds impossible, except for the following scientific considerations. Vlatko Vedral, professor of Physics at the University of Oxford specializing in quantum theory and whose research papers are widely cited, expresses the concept this way:

> The most fundamental definition of reality is not matter or energy,
> but *information*–and it is the processing of information that lies at
> the root of all physical, biological, economic, and social phenomena.

Another way this is expressed is that all mass and energy are entirely “mathematical probability waves” that only become “real” after they are observed or measured. For example, it’s believed that solar fusion would not occur in the sun without *quantum tunneling*. All these strange and very disturbing behaviors leads many physicists to believe that there’s about a 50:50 chance that we actually live in a simulation! Here’s [an article from Scientific American](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/confirmed-we-live-in-a-simulation/) that describes the evidence for the *Simulation Hypothesis*.

If true, stars could indeed fall to earth and the sky could indeed vanish like a (3D) scroll being rolled up in the simulation. Anything could happen—as it already does in popular video games.

In conclusion, any of these interpretations are possible and might be a combination of symbolic and literal. And there’s also the possibility of *superimposition* such as was the case of the King of Tyre and Satan in Ezekiel 28:11-19, where the King of Tyre was certainly not “in Eden, the garden of God,” or the “guardian cherub, from the midst of the stones of fire.”

Finally, in addition to the previously mentioned factors, one might also ask what the purpose of the visions in Revelation are intended to serve.

The metaphorical and literal bottom line here is that the interpretation of these and other passages in Revelation remain controversial, but the best approach is to gather as much as possible for and against each interpretation and decide what's the most likely rather than proof-texting the one that appeals to you the most.

Answer (score 0):

My personal theory is that they simply disappear from view. Atmospheric pollution would account for that, and would also account for the relative darkening of sun and moon in the previous verse. The heavy shaking of the ground would help to account for the atmospheric pollution. This episode is about the great earthquake and the side-effects, and most of all it is about the human reaction.